# How to replicate specifc rows between slaves

Tags: mysql, database-replication

Is it possible to setup a group replication with this behaviour using MySQL?
[image: Grou Replication which only some columns in the same table are replicated]

If not, which databases could offer me this option?

Comment: which way is the replication going?  Are the entries in the computers table rows?

Comment: I need to setup as a bidirectional replication

Comment: I already have a group replication working in MySQL, but all the computers have information about all the others. I could create a View for each one, but I don't want unessessaries syncrhonizations, since in the future may be a lot of Computers.